# Action Listener on Zoom in Button

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to put action listener on the zoom in button of my website,so that when map moves(zoom in) map 2 also zoom in.I had tried the moveend function but that doesnt worked out.How can I do that?

Comment: You can do this by the Zoom_changed Function()

//Zooming

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed', function () {
    var newCenter1 = map.getCenter();
    var z=map.getZoom();
    map1.setZoom(z);
});
Just did it now..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by the `zoom_changed` function:

```
//Zooming
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed', function ()
{
    var newCenter1 = map.getCenter();
    var z=map.getZoom();
    map1.setZoom(z);
});
```